# HTML, pics and text

Tags: html, css

I need to Write a text on the left side of the screen and on the right of it i need the images.
I used a code that puts the text between the 2 images on the side, i want the text will be on top, Here is my code:

```html
<table width="1400" height="10">
  <tr height="10px">
    <td align="left">
      <p style="color:lime; width:50%">
        Text
      </p>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
      <p style="color:Lime; width:50%">
        The next link will send u to the "transfer Market" page
      </p>
      <a href="https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/lionel-messi/profil/spieler/28003" targer="_blank">The Page</a>
      <br />
      <img src="pics/pic4.jpg" />
      <br />
      <img src="pics/pic6.jpg" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you want make this , only in table ?

Comment: any way making this work is fine with me

Comment: unless this is a template for an email address, tables shouldn't be used for layouts. Only for tabular data. Use divs. Also inline CSS is a bad idea and a one-way ticket to nightmarish maintainability.

Answer (score -1):

Like mentioned in the comments, tables are not the best choice for layout.
There are many other ways to do this including [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox), [grids](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) or even good old [floats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Floats).

Just to give you an example with floats:

```css
    
    .wrapper::after {
      content:'';
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
      
    .left, .right {
      display: block:
      position: relative;
      width: 50%;
      float: left;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div> 
  <div class="right">
    <p>The next link will send u to the "transfer Market" page</p>
    <img src="pics/pic4.jpg" />
    <img src="pics/pic6.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I also added a `clear: both` to the wrapper so the following content doesn't get mixed up by the floats.

Comment: floats are a bad idea - leads to a lot of unexpected behaviour

Comment: @treyBake Floats are perfectly fine when cleared properly. But I admit there are more "modern" solutions to the problem which I mentioned as well, although their [browser support still is a bit sketchy](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid), if you need to cater IE.